# Adding Google Content Experiments code to a single page of Angular 1 application

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-analytics

I have Google Content Experiments code which looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}(function(){var
   k='1234566789-0',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie;
   if(l.search.indexOf('utm_expid='+k)>0)return;
   function f(n){if(c){var i=c.indexOf(n+'=');if(i>-1){var j=c.
   indexOf(';',i);return escape(c.substring(i+n.length+1,j<0?c.
       length:j))}}}var x=f('__utmx'),xx=f('__utmxx'),h=l.hash;d.write(
     '<sc'+'ript src="'+'http'+(l.protocol=='https:'?'s://ssl':
       '://www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga_exp.js?'+'utmxkey='+k+
     '&utmx='+(x?x:'')+'&utmxx='+(xx?xx:'')+'&utmxtime='+new Date().
     valueOf()+(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+
     '" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><\/sc'+'ript>')})();
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">utmx('url','A/B');</script>
```

I need to add it to an Angular app, but only to a single page. The problem is that it uses `document.write()` which makes the page go blank if added dynamically. If I add it statically to the main `index.html` it will load on all pages, not just the one I want. Is there a way around this? I believe it could be done with server-side rendering, but I don't have it set up right now, and doing it just for this little script seems like an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You should use content experiments api instead https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side

But, it doesn't work well with Single Page Apps, yet...